# ReactJS: Compare props and state on shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I want to check all properties and state if they are changed, return true if any changed and make a base component for all my root components.

I'm wondering if it won't be the best practice and make my components slow.
Also, what I did always returns true:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(newProps, newState) {
    if (newState == this.state && this.props == newProps) {
        console.log('false');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('true');
    return true;
},
```

1. Is there anything wrong with my code?
2. Should I check for every variable inside props and state?
3. Won't check for objects inside them make it slow depending on their size?

Comment: I think you want to have a look at `PureRenderMixin`: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html. `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true` by default. You can make your app more performant by properly implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` so that it does not have to render the subtree again.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is considered best practice to compare props and state in `shouldComponentUpdate` to determine whether or not you should re-render your component.

As for why it's always evaluating to true, I believe your if statement isn't performing a deep object comparison and is registering your previous and current props and state as different objects.

I don't know why you want to check every field in both objects anyway because React won't even try to re-render the component if the props or state hasn't changed so the very fact the `shouldComponentUpdate` method was called means something MUST have changed. `shouldComponentUpdate` is much better implemented to check maybe a few props or state for changes and decide whether to re-render based on that.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a problem in most of the tutorials I've seen (including the official docs) in the way that stores are accessed. Usually what I see is something like this:

```
// MyStore.js

var _data = {};

var MyStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {

  get: function() {
    return _data;
  },

  ...

});
```

When I used this pattern, I found that the `newProps` and `newState` in functions like `shouldComponentUpdate` always evaluate as equal to this.props and this.state. I think the reason is that the store is returning a direct reference to its mutable `_data` object.

In my case the problem was solved by returning a copy of `_data` rather than the object itself, like so:

```
  get: function() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_data));
  },
```

So I'd say check your stores and make sure you're not returning any direct references to their private data object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper function to do the comparison efficiently.

```
var shallowCompare = require('react-addons-shallow-compare');
export class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
  }

  render() {
    return <div className={this.props.className}>foo</div>;
  }
}
```