# Using PureRenderMixin with hardcoded props

Tags: reactjs

I have made a React component called Graph:

```
<Graph
    chartOptions={{forceY: [0, 100]}}
    graphData={graphData}
/>
```

I want to implement shouldComponentUpdate to draw the graph only when needed. I looked into using the PureRenderMixin which compares the props. However, my chartOptions is a new object with the same contents every time this code is run. I want the chartOptions to be the same object every time, so I can properly compare the props. How can I do this?

Comment: Refer to understand shouldComponentUpdate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353702/reactjs-check-props-and-state-on-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: You can move it to an instance property or variable outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of values in forceY is important, the following code should work...

In Graph component -

```
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(newProps, newState){
       if(!_.isEqual(this.props.chartOptions.forceY, newProps.chartOptions.forceY)){
        return false;
       }

       return (newProps != this.props && newState != this.state);
    }
```

The _ is a [lodash](https://lodash.com/) import. You can use this library to compare the new array with the existing one. Or you can implement your own equality comparer based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).